# How to display the name of the program instead of sudo in byobu?

Tags: byobu, tmux

I'm using byobu when working on the shell. If I start a program the name of it is displayed in the status line. However when something is prefixed with `sudo` it just displays sudo (`sudo tail -F /var/log/syslog`). I want it to display the name of the program, the second argument (`tail` in my example above). How can I do this?

Comment: I'm currently searching for an answer on this, and have been for a while. Honestly, it doesn't appear to be possible by default. I'll take a look at the source and see if it can be modified to support command-line arguments, then recompiled, but that may be a bit too much for what you're trying to do. Also, I'm fairly inexperienced and will probably not be very helpful. Sorry!

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't gotten anywhere. I wish I could be more helpful. There's nothing more that I can do, but maybe (hopefully) this will be implemented by byobu developers in the future,

Comment: Why dont you make a pull request?